# Problems with hexadecimal table in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, converter

I want to convert from binary to hexadecimal but I found a few problems with VHDL in Quartus II.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Hexadecimal is port


(
hexadecimal: in integer range 0 to 9; 
binario: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end Hexadecimal;
architecture comportamiento of Hexadecimal is
begin
    process (hexadecimal)
    begin
        If hexadecimal = 0 then
            binario <= "0000";
        elsif hexadecimal = 1 then
            binario <= "0001";
        elsif hexadecimal = 2 then
            binario <= "0010";
        elsif hexadecimal = 3 then
            binario <= "0011";
        elsif hexadecimal = 4 then
            binario <= "0100";
        elsif hexadecimal = 5 then
            binario <= "0101";
        elsif hexadecimal = 6 then
            binario <= "0110";
        elsif hexadecimal = 7 then
            binario <= "0111";
        elsif hexadecimal = 8 then
            binario <= "1000";
        elsif hexadecimal = 9 then
            binario <= "1001";
        elsif hexadecimal = 'A' then
            binario <= "1010";
        elsif hexadecimal = 'B' then
            binario <= "1011";
        elsif hexadecimal = 'C' then
            binario <= "1100";
        elsif hexadecimal = 'D' then
            binario <= "1101";
        elsif hexadecimal = 'E' then
            binario <= "1110";
        else
            binario <= "1111";
        end if;
    end process;
end comportamiento;
```

But when I try to compile it, it throws this error:

```
Error (10327): VHDL error at Hexadecimal.vhd(33): can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0 possible definitions
```

I came to this forum at last because I tried everything. I hope you guys know how to solve this.

Comment: First you say hexadecimal is in the range 0 to 9. Then you check if it's equal to A, B, C, etc. I don't know VHDL, but there's probably a problem there.

Comment: Yes that is wrong . Also you are not converting binary to hexadecimal but the other way around. Note that an *integer* hexadecimal number already HAS the right binary bits. All you need is to convert from integer to std_logic_vector.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Type conversion is possibly a easier and more efficient way to do this.
For hex to std_logic use

binario <= to_stdlogicvector(hexadecimal);

Make sure you include the ieee std_logic_arith package.

Comment: Better to use the standard libraries.